# New tag popup is hidden behind edit review popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, tag-watching

The new tag popup appears behind edit review popup windows (**so it can't be seen**).

To reproduce:

- Internet Explorer 11 (I cannot test other browsers from work *[he says, crying in the corner]*)

  - Edit: bug confirmed in Chrome and Firefox too in comments.
- Click on the `edit (1)` link for a pending question edit
- Hover over any of the tags to view the description

[image: issue on hover]

I often do this if I'm unsure whether a tag edit is appropriate, now I have to actually click the link to read the tag description on its own page...

Comment: The same problem is reproducible in  firefox

Comment: And in chrome...

Comment: [status-review]... "will review this and determine whether we want the popup to be above or below modal"... wait... WAT?

Comment: @TinyGiant Or "whether it's as simple to move it above the modal as it seems", more likely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

This is a regression of [Hovering a tag when viewing a suggested edit directly from the question page shows the tag popup behind the edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129465/hovering-a-tag-when-viewing-a-suggested-edit-directly-from-the-question-page-sho).  The fix in that question set the z-index of the popup to 1002 to be higher than that of `.lightbox-panel`.  At some point, things changed and the z-index to beat jumped from 1001 to 8951.  Maybe this happened after the tag watching rollout or maybe no one noticed because the old popup was smaller and hid more easily.

Now instead of hard-coding the z-index, we're checking for the existence of `.lightbox` and applying a higher z-index if present.

Comment: Thanks for the diagnosis, proposed fix sounds sensible! Cheers