# Buggy UI when a badge is earned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges, profile-page

I just earned the Commentator badge, and this is what the UI looked like:
[image]

Is this right? You can't even read the text at the bottom unless you hover over each of those buttons. Surely there must be another way to display this message, like moving the dark blue part up a little?

Browser: Chrome, Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Do mention the browser you use.  And if you did anything to hide the "Job recommendations" section.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think I hid anything...

Comment: That looks like a z-index gone wrong.That happens [now and then](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371457/578411)

Comment: This happened to me on Firefox 62.0.2 (64-bit) on Meta Stack Exchange.  Looks like the gap between the top and bottom is too large (too much empty space).

Comment: Cross-dupe on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316061/youve-earned-badge-panel-layouts-are-broken

Comment: Same happening with me....

Comment: Does anybody know when it will be fixed? Because on Chrome 46.0 it also happens.

Comment: Firefox 62.0.3 and Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 also do this

Comment: FYI: this bug has been forwarded to the design team and is awaiting triage.

Comment: Edge 44.17763.1.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should be fixed now:

[image: image of new badge alert without overlap on tabs below]

Answer (score 16):

The same happens in Google Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) Windows 10.

[image: bug stack]

The problem seems to be the class `h100` which sets `height: 100%`. Removing it fixes the issue in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: [Same here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcMUz.png). Win10 Enterprise, same version of Chrome. Confirmed.

Comment: Fixes the issue, used UserCSS (Chrome Extension) to fix it temporarily.

Answer (score 15):

I noticed the same thing in **Ask Ubuntu** a couple of days ago:

[image]

Firefox 62.0 (64-bit)

Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0

Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Kernel 4.13.0-36-generic (I've been meaning to upgrade honest)

Answer (score 4):

Same in Safari 11 and Google Chrome 69.0.3497:

> [image]

Comment: Happened also to me, with Safari 11.

Answer (score 3):

While waiting for a fix, a small user script to work around...

```
/** @preserve
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Fix New Badge Box
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://stackexchange.com/users/*
// @match        https://*.stackexchange.com/users/*
// @match        https://*.stackoverflow.com/users/*
// @match        https://*.mathoverflow.net/users/*
// @match        https://*.serverfault.com/users/*
// @match        https://*.askubuntu.com/users/*
// @match        https://*.stackapps.com/users/*
// @match        https://*.superuser.com/users/*
// ==/UserScript==
*/

var badgeBox = document.getElementsByClassName('js-congrats-next-badge');
if (badgeBox.length) {
    var badgeDiv = badgeBox[0].parentElement;
    badgeDiv.previousElementSibling.appendChild(badgeDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have the same issue with FireFox on Windows 10
[image]

Comment: You're hiding your reputation?